# Having problems with **advance formatting method syntax**?

Tags: python, string.format

What is the value 0 in front of [].

```
>>>somelist = list('SPAM')

>>>'first = {0[0]}, third = {0[2]}' .format(somelist)

'first=S, third=A'
```

Comment: Have you checked `format` docs?

Comment: I think it's explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

`0` represents the first argument of the `format` function, which is `somelist`.

This means that this `0` will be replaced by `somelist` and then its first (`[0]`) and third (`[2]`) elements are used in the string.

Therefore `0` is `['S', 'P', 'A', 'M']`, `0[0]` is `'S'` and `0[2]` is `'A'`.